# Typo3 tt_news Wrap title of news with particular category

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I have a lot of news items with different categories.
Code below works, but it wraps titles of all news in the same way.

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList {
    title_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="my-class">|</div>
    title_stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```

I need to wrap title depending on the category of the news item.
Something like this **(pseudo-code)**:

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList {

    if (category == 1):
        title_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="special-class">|</div>
    else:
        title_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="my-class">|</div>

    title_stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your category into a global variable or global string (somewhere in the `$GLOBALS` array, perhaps), you could use [globalVar](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalvar) or [globalString](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalstring). See [Conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Index.html#conditions) for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I can not test now this because I usually use the extension news instead of tt_news, but this snippet may could help. You can use a [CASE](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Case/Index.html) object and you can use a register to handle the category uid for the "current" record.

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList {
    title_stdWrap.wrap = CASE
    title_stdWrap.wrap {
        key.data = register:newsCategoryUid

        default = TEXT
        default.value = <div class="my-class">|</div>

        1 = TEXT
        1 = <div class="special-class">|</div>
    }
    title_stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```

See here also an example which describe a similar request as yours: [Different wraps](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/ExtNews/Configuration/Registers/Index.html#different-wraps-by-category)